# Python list function variable wrongly assigned

Tags: python, list, function

I am currently learning python and I face a problem, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the task :

- Given a list of integers, moves all non-zero numbers to the beginning of the list and moves all zeros to the end of the list.
- This function returns nothing and changes the given list itself.
  For example:

  - After calling `move_zero([0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4])`, the given list should be `[1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0]` and the function **returns nothing**
  - After calling `move_zero([0,1,2,0,1])`, the given list should be `[1,2,1,0,0]` and the function **returns nothing**
  - After calling `move_zero([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`, the given list should be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and the function **returns nothing**
  - After calling `move_zero([])`, the given list should be `[]` and the function **returns nothing**

Here is my code :

```py
def move_zero(lst):
  
    list1 = [] #initialise list which will contain != 0 numbers
    list2 = [] #initialise list which will contain == 0 numbers
    for i in lst:
        if i != 0:
            list1.append(i)
        else :
            list2.append(i)
            
    lst = list1 + list2 
    
    return
```

My function doesn't return anything as asked, but when I `print(lst)` outside the function, I get the initial list again.
I understand that I am wrongly assigning a variable, but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: You are not returning anything at the end so ofcourse it will do nothing.

Comment: Well, you don't `return` anything…!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If the function must return `None`

This is because you reassign list to a new list made with `list1 + list2`.
You need to modify the list you send to your function with the temporary list made with the concatenation of `list1` and `list2`.

```py
def move_zero(lst):
    no_zero = list()
    only_zero = list()
    for i in lst:
        if i != 0:
            no_zero.append(i)
        else:
            only_zero.append(i)

    temp = no_zero + only_zero 
    i = 0
    for e in temp:
        lst[i] = e
        i += 1

    return  # return None is implicit, you can remove this line

a = [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4]
print(move_zero(a), a)
```

#### If you can use `enumerate()`

```py
    temp = no_zero + only_zero
    for i, e in enumerate(temp):
        lst[i] = e
```

#### If you can use `list.clear()` and `list.extend()`

```py
    temp = no_zero + only_zero 
    lst.clear()
    lst.extend(temp)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as everyone else mentioning returning the list which is clearly prohibited in the question. Worth to mention that this mainly is a exercise to learn about mutable types in python so I want to reference this for further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your function is that you are not returning `lst` at the end of your function, which you could then re-assign over the original list.

More concisely, you can just use `sorted` with a `key` that checks if the element is zero or not.

```
def move_zero(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda i: i == 0)

>>> move_zero([0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> move_zero([0,1,2,0,1])
[1, 2, 1, 0, 0]
>>> move_zero([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

If you wanted to sort the list in-place instead of making a new one, you could replace the implementation with

```
def move_zero(lst):
    lst.sort(key=lambda i: i == 0)
```

Comment: Since the task is to do in-place sort, maybe you should at least put the last part of your answer first ?

Comment: I can't return lst at the end of the function it is prohibited in the given task

Comment: @maverick Then the second alternative in my answer should work as an in-place version

Answer (score 0):

```
def moveZeros(arr): 
  
return [nonZero for nonZero in arr if nonZero!=0] + \ 
       [Zero for Zero in arr if Zero==0] 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    arr = [1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 0, 5, 0] 
    print (moveZeros(arr))
```

Try this it is a better method check out the geeks for geeks article.
Below is your code corrected.

```
def move_zero(lst):
  list1 = [] #initialise list which will contain != 0 numbers
  list2 = [] #initialise list which will contain == 0 numbers
  for i in lst:
     if i != 0:
       list1.append(i)
     else :
       list2.append(i)

  lst.clear()
  lst = list1 + list2 

lst = [0,1,4,5,0,9,7]
move_zero(lst[:])
print(lst)
```

You can refer to this link.
https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php.
To change the value of list in place please refer to @DorianTurba's answer above

Comment: The function have to return nothing and change the list in-place.

Comment: @DorianTurba I have modified the code tell me if it's even I am intrigued now

Comment: the `lst` you create at the end of `move_zero()` is a ref that now point to a list local to the function. This does not change the list in place.

Comment: @DorianTurba I saw your answer, I do not understand how extend() works, can you please explain?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists "Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable."